# Redirect standard output and standard err when executing a method

Tags: fantom

I have a program that tests each method in a `Test#` subclass and outputs XML in JUnit's XML format.

For instance:

```
class ExampleTest : Test
{
  Void testOne()
  {
   ... 
  }
}
```

I want to execute the `testOne` method and capture the standard output and standard error produced in it. This `out` and `err` output will be included in the XML report.

My first idea was to look at `sys::Env`. The environment class `sys::Env` has `err` and `out` but are readonly.

My second idea is that `sys::Process` can be launched for each test method and redirect `sys::Process#.err` and `sys::Process#.out` in it, but I'm afraid it will be very slow.

There is other way to do it?

Comment: Being able to redirect `StdIn` and `StdOut` without having to replace `Env` indeed would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to redirect output from your current process (and really should not).

If the output absolutely has to be `stdout/err` - you'll need to go the Process route.  You'll take the fork/jvm/stream setup hit, but that may be negligible compared to your test runtime.

A better option would be to log using the [Logging API](http://fantom.org/doc/docLang/Logging) - which will give more control over what gets logged, and where things go.